# Centring of Google Maps on a Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, mobile

I have a problem with Google Maps not centring correctly on a mobile phone. (I see the problem on Android Lollipop. It doesn't seem to happen with an ancient old iPhone 3. I don't know about others.)

A map is opened in a floatbox, but the first time it is opened the point which I specified as the centre is actually in the top left corner. If I close the floatbox and open it again, the map displays correctly.

I have already searched the web for the problem and found suggestions about resizing and recentring, so I added this to the code.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.setCenter(thisLatlng);
```

Perhaps the lines are in the wrong place in the code, although I have tried numerous variations without success. The complete code for the map is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/infobox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/downloadxml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
     // global "map" variable
      var map = null;

  var image = {
      url: '../images/small_icon.gif',
      size: new google.maps.Size(22, 27),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(11, 25)
  };
  var hotelimage = {
      url: '../images/hotel_icon.gif',
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 35)
  };

// InfoBox
 var boxText = document.createElement("div");
        boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid #4d6eb0; margin-top: 8px; background: white; padding: 5px;";

        var ibOptions = {
         content: boxText
        ,closeBoxURL: ""
        ,disableAutoPan: false
        ,enableEventPropagation: true
        ,maxWidth: 0
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(15, -50)
        ,boxStyle: { 
         width: "160px"
         }
        };

// global "infobox" variable
  var ib = new InfoBox(ibOptions);

////////////////////////
// A function to create the markers and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, hotel) {
    var contentString = hotel;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        icon: image,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        boxText.innerHTML = contentString;
        ib.open(map, marker);
        });
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        ib.close(map, marker);
        });
}

function initialize() {
      var lat = 0;
      var lng = 0;
      var zoom = 0;
      var hotelname = 0;
      var query = location.search.substring(1);
      query = query.replace(/\+/g, " ");
      var pairs = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
    var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
    var argname = pairs[i].substring(0,pos).toLowerCase();
    var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1);
        if (argname == "lat") {lat = parseFloat(value);}
        if (argname == "lng") {lng = parseFloat(value);}
        if (argname == "zoom") {zoom = parseInt(value);}
        if (argname == "hotel") {hotelname = unescape(value);}
      }
  var thisLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  var mapOptions = {
center: thisLatlng,
zoom: zoom,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   streetViewControl: true,
   scaleControl: true,
   zoomControl: true
   }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

//////////////////////
  var hotelmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: thisLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: hotelimage,
      zIndex: 9999
  });

var style_nopoi = [{"featureType": "poi", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}]; // Styles, removes points-of-interest. Lots of other possibilities.
map.setOptions({styles: style_nopoi});  // Applies the style to the map
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.setCenter(thisLatlng); // Seems to fix random centring problem on mobiles

      google.maps.event.addListener(hotelmarker, 'mouseover', function() {
        boxText.innerHTML = hotelname;
        ib.open(map, hotelmarker);
        });
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        ib.close(map, hotelmarker);
        });

////////////////////

      downloadUrl("php-to-xml.php", function(doc) {
        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
          var hotel=markers[i].getAttribute("hotel");
          var html=markers[i].getAttribute("html");

          createMarker(point,html);
        }

      });
    }

//]]>
</script> 
</head> 

<body onload="initialize()"> 
<div id="content">
<h1>Location - <?php echo $hotel; ?></h1>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<br />
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

I have to confess to not understanding all of what is going on in the page. I cobbled it together from several sources, but there is a lot about javascript that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I may have solved it. It's a bit difficult to be sure because the problem seemed to occur randomly.

I read up some more on google.maps.event.addListener and then did a bit of experimenting.

If the map was displaying wrongly this code enabled it to be corrected with a click on the screen

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
map.setCenter(thisLatlng);
});
```

That was good for proof-of-concept but no help if the user didn't know they had to click. So I tried

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'load', function() {
    map.setCenter(thisLatlng);
});
```

That didn't work. Not entirely surprisingly as the initialize function is controlled by body onload anyway. So I looked for something else that would happen without any action from the user, and I ended up with

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    map.setCenter(thisLatlng);
});
```

EDIT That failed too. When someone scrolls the map away from the original position Google Maps has to add some extra tiles so 'tilesloaded' then flips it back to the original centre.

EDIT AGAIN I tried again, modifying the code so that it only works once:

```
var loadcnt = 0;
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
        if (loadcnt==0) {
        map.setCenter(thisLatlng);
        loadcnt=loadcnt+1;
        }
        });
```

Fingers crossed!